# How to post form by clicking in anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, form-submit

How to submit form by clicking in a element ?

I tried code below but Chrome sends it using http GET method. How to fix this so that form is sent using POST method ?

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="_form" method='post' target='_blank'>
        <input type="email" value="me@company.com" name="_email" />
        <a href='SendEMail?_entity=DokGReport&amp;_dokumnrs=135361'
           id='sendemail' class='button'>
            Send
        </a>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#sendemail').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-mail-closed" } })
              .click(function () {
                  $('#_form')[0].action = $(this).attr('href');
                  $('#_form')[0].submit();
              });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hmm... try adding the `_entity` and your other params as hidden input fields, ie `<input type="hidden" name="_entity" value="DokGReport" />` etc, and remove them from the action URL.

Comment: why not define action of form as form attributes?

Comment: @Daiwei I'll take a guess: in the real application there can be multiple links, so the action depends on which one he clicks on.

Comment: Form contains number of a elements. Every element click should post to different URL and use POST method to get all form data. So single action cannot used.

Comment: Why are you doing it with anchors? You can have multiple `submit` buttons, and they can each have a `formaction` attribute to override the form's `action`.

Comment: Does adding `return false` to the click handler solve the problem?

Comment: try change $('#_form')[0].action = $(this).attr('href'); to $('#_form').attr({action: $(this).attr('href')}); and change submit to $('#_form').submit()

Comment: @Barmar, it looks <= IE9 doesn't support `formaction` on `submit` elements, but it's good to know about that attribute.

Comment: @Barmar it looks like return false from click solves the issue. Should I still change a elements to multiple submit buttons ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of clicking on the anchor, which is to follow the link:

```
    $(function () {
        $('#sendemail').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-mail-closed" } })
          .click(function (e) {
              e.preventDefault(); // Don't follow the link normally
              $('#_form').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();
          });

    });
```

Comment: I posted related question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20767487/how-to-force-validation-of-input-type-email-element-before-form-posting-from-anc