# How to force validation of input type=email element before form posting from anchor

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-ui, validation

Code below from [How to post form by clicking in anchor element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20767094/how-to-post-form-by-clicking-in-anchor-element) is used to post email address using a element. POST method must be used since real form contains lot of large fields.

If invalid e-mail address is entered (without @ sign), this invalid email is posted.
I expect that current Chrome performs basic email validation and does not allow email addresses without @ characters.

How to force browser to validate email address before submit ?

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="_form" method='post' target='_blank'>
        <input type="email" value="me@company.com" name="_email" />
        <a href='SendEMail?_entity=DokGReport&amp;_dokumnrs=135361'
           id='sendemail' class='button'>
            Send
        </a>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#sendemail').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-mail-closed" } })
              .click(function () {
                  e.preventDefault(); 
                  $('#_form').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();
              });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

From answer I got information that to enable native hmtl5 validation tooltip and allow to use older non html5 browsers also we need to simulate click in hidden submit button.

I tried code below but validation tooltip does not appear and form is not submitted.
How to fix?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="_form" method='post'>
        <input type="email" value="me@company.com" name="_email" />
        <button type="button" id='sendemail' 
          data-url='SendEMail?_entity=Report&amp;_dokumnrs=135361'>
        Perform HTMl5 validation and show error message, post on success only.
           Post without validation if browser does not support html5
        </button>
    <button type="submit" style='visibility:hidden' id='realSubmit' />
    </form>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#sendemail').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-mail-closed" } })
            .on('click', function () {
              showModeless('Sending e-mail. please wait');
              $('#_form').attr('action', $(this).attr('data-url'));
              if ($('#realsubmit').click()) {
                // html5 validation with tooltip succeeds or browser does not support it
     // avoid duplicate submits if clicked multiple times           
     $('#_form').prop('disabled', true);
                }
              });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add this at the top, in case you haven't yet:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Then try:

```
$(function () {
            $('#sendemail').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-mail-closed" } })
              .click(function (e) {  // this line changed
                  e.preventDefault(); 
                  // Below formIsValid is custom validation, checkVlidity invokes HTML5 validation
                  if(formIsValid() && !document.getElementById("_form").checkValidity())
                  {
                      $('#_form').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();
                  }
              });
```

This allows you to piggyback on the HTML5 validation. However, you'll notice that the little toolip doesn't show up. The only way I have found to programmatically invoke that is this library:

https://github.com/lgersman/jquery.orangevolt-ampere/blob/master/src/jquery.html5validation.js

Comment: Can I use validation provided by input type='email' or should I implement validation myself?

Comment: you would put custom validation in the `formIsValid` function. The HTML5 validation has already occured. See this: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/1-email.html

Comment: HTML5 validation does NOT occur in code provided in question. It occurs in your sample link but in my code pressing tab and clicking anchor posts wrong email without any error. How to force same validation as in your sample in code posted in question?

Comment: I've changed my answer to reflect what I think you want. Couple of things, first it doesn't look like you can trigger the little bubbles automatically. Got that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719283/how-to-trigger-native-validation-bubble-tooltips-for-form-validation-using-javas, second your code is not preventing the default action, it's just going to the link, to be sure your code it working properly I'd recommend making the `href="#"` and adding `data-url='your_form_action'` and using that instead.

Comment: Custom validation is not required. Submit without validation on non html5 browsers is required. In html5 browsers message and submit cancel if html5 validation fails is required. Your code causes error on checkValidity method on non-html5 browsers and does not show validation failure message on html5 borwsers. I updated question based in your answer answer but validation tooltip does not appear and form is not submitted. How to fix?

Comment: @Andrus I addressed the validation tooltip in my previous comment. Try that link.

Comment: I used code from link from referenced answer: ´$('#realsubmit').click()´ in updated code in question. This simulates click on submit and must show tooltip or invoke submit if browser does not support html5 email validation.

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear. I meant use this library that is referenced in the link: https://github.com/lgersman/jquery.orangevolt-ampere/blob/master/src/jquery.html5validation.js

Comment: I used http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-September/033318.html  statement: `I guess submitControl.click() should work and isn't that hacky` This seems better: no need for plugin as in your link. Why updated code in question fails for this?

Comment: The updated code checks validation using html5, but you didn't specify you wanted the tooltip. A hidden submit work, does seem a bit hacky though. Anyway glad you solved your problem, happy coding!

Comment: I changed anchors to <input type='submit'> buttons with formacton attribute. This allows html validation natively